# Reapplying for a Brazilian VITEM I after cancellation

Tags: visa, canadian-citizens, brazil

My husband and I (Canadian citizens) have been volunteering in Brazil since February under a VITEM I visa. Due to ignorance on our part, we failed to register at the PF within 30 days and because of this, when we returned after travelling outside of the country in September, our visas were cancelled upon re-entry. We are contemplating whether to reapply or to just take an early exit from our volunteer work.

My question is, how does Brazil usually deal with visa applications with history of cancellation? Are we pretty much out of luck in trying for another one? Or do we have a decent chance at success?